# How to use uipagecontroll For pagging Two diffrent ViewController

Tags: iphone

I am try Different-Different Way but and also search on google but no solution found

Comment: Do you mean use one pagecontrol to control two scroll views?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what it is you're trying to achieve, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to pageing btween two class using scrollview